# Add before_content and after_content to register_sidebar

Tags: php, functions, widgets, register-sidebar

Is there any way to add two new functions, `before_content` and `after_content` to the `register_sidebar` function? These would work like `before_title` and `after_title`, except it would wrap everything that comes after the title.

I've found [this thread](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/add-html-wrapper-around-widget-content) which has some useful information, but every mentioned approach has flaws.

For example, inserting the required code in `after_title` and `after_widget` can result in broken code if a title isn't set. The solution would be to duplicate the opening div in `before_widget` and close it out again in `before_title` then reopen it in `before_title`, but that creates an empty div if a title *is* set.

Ideally, I'd like to do this:

```
register_sidebar(array(
    "id"             => "sidebar",
    "name"           => "Sidebar",
    "before_widget"  => "<div class='box box_push'>",
    "before_title"   => "<div class='box-hd'>",
    "after_title"    => "</div>",
    "before_content" => "<div class='box box-bd'>"
    "after_content"  => "</div>";
    "after_widget"   => "</div>",
));
```

Which would output as:

```
<div class="box box_push">
    <div class="box-hd">
        <!-- widget title -->
    </div>

    <div class="box box-bd">
        <!-- widget content-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limitation is down to the existing arguments and how pretty much all widgets typically output content:

```
echo $args['before_widget'];
if ( $title ) {
    echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
}

// Widget content

echo $args['after_widget'];
```

Some widgets may offer before/after content hooks, but if you want a "global" fix there's no surefire way around it.

The only solution I can see is to add the wrap twice and use CSS `:empty` to hide the leftovers:

```
register_sidebar(
    array(
        'before_widget'  => '<div class="box box_push"><div class="box box-bd">',
        'before_title'   => '</div>', // If we have a title, close the wrap above
        'after_title'    => '<div class="box box-bd">', // Now open another one
        'after_widget'   => '</div></div>',
    )
);
```

So with widgets that have titles, you'll end up with:

```
<div class="box box_push">
    <div class="box box-bd"></div>
    Widget Title

    <div class="box box-bd">
        Widget content
    </div>
</div>
```

Enter the aforementioned CSS:

```
.box-bd:empty {
    display: none;
}
```

This will hide that first redundant wrap. A little dirty, I know, but it means title or no title, you'll always have your content wrapped in `.box-bd`.

Comment: I guess this'll work for now, but I really feel like this should be built in to WordPress. I'm particularly worried about older browsers not recognizing the `:empty` pseudo class.

Comment: Even if it does get added to WordPress, you'll still need all widget authors out there to update their code... bit of a long shot.

Comment: I don't know that's necessarily true, if it's blank by default it'd be up to theme makers to bug test.